# Elasticsearch 200 and Green status - no response

Tags: elasticsearch

After many trials and errors, here is the pattern:
1 Node: Works perfect
2 Nodes: root / query show 200, and cluster health is green, but cannot index new doc (no response). Search query has no response too. But once I shut down one node, everything would work again.

I do make sure that port 9300 firewall is open between the nodes. Am I missing other important config? The cluster API reports 2 nodes, so the communication should be fine. But is there other factor that prevent new documents from indexing in the two nodes?

Comment: thats not true, elasticsearch is using port 9300 as standard port for internode communication. 92** is used for http/rest normally. If this port is already in use then port 9301 and so on is used. But without any logfiles or more details no helpful answer is possible. OP please provide logs and info about environment (es version, java version, OS details)

Comment: Check if the folder elasticsearch needs can be created (config/data/logs/work). When you are checking them make sure they are writeable by the user running elasticsearch.

Comment: Apologies that is correct. Must of been half asleep.